# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'

Tags: c#

why do I have to cast an object when I assign its value to a variable, but if I used the `GetType()` function it returns its value.
Sorry my English is bad, but I hope you understood what I'm talking about.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object o = true;
        Console.WriteLine(o.GetType()); //System.Boolean
        bool s = o; //Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

Comment: Guys, I know I need a cast. I didn't mean how to fix that error, I meant why the object appears as a bool when I use the GetType() function but I can't convert it implicitly to another bool variable.

Comment: @Heisenberg: Because the *compile-time* type is `object`, but the *execution-time* type is `System.Boolean`.

Comment: @Heisenberg: it's runtime type vs. compile-time/lexical type. The lexical type is `object`, and that's what the compiler works with. The compiler doesn't know that you actually stashed a `bool` in there. So to tell the compiler that you think you did, you have to include a cast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between the *compile-time* type of a variable, and the *execution-time* type of its value. The compiler uses the compile-time type to look up members (e.g. methods) and work out what conversions are available. This includes overload resolution, too.

The execution-time type is used for *overriding*, and `GetType()` (which is executed at execution-time, of course) returns the execution-time type of a value. For example:

```
 object x = "hello";
 Console.WriteLine(x.GetType()); // System.String
 Console.WriteLine(x.Length); // Compile-time error
```

Here the compile-time type of `x` is `object` (aka `System.Object`) which doesn't have a `Length` property - so you get a compile-time failure, even though at *execution* time, the value of `x` will be a reference to a string.

You can use the `dynamic` type to force binding to occur at execution time instead, using the execution-time type of the variable:

```
dynamic x = "hello";
Console.WriteLine(x.Length); // Uses String.Length and prints 5
x = new object[10];
Console.WriteLine(x.Length); // Uses Array.Length and prints 10
```

However, that's usually a last resort in my experience, for situations which really are dynamic (e.g. accessing JSON data where there *is* no compile-time type).

Answer (score 3):

```
bool s = (bool)o;
```

You should write it like this, you need to cast it.

> Explicit conversions (casts): Explicit conversions require a cast
>   operator. Casting is required when information might be lost in the
>   conversion, or when the conversion might not succeed for other
>   reasons.  Typical examples include numeric conversion to a type that
>   has less precision or a smaller range, and conversion of a base-class
>   instance to a derived class.

You can check this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) for more information. Also you can read about [boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

Comment: Yes I know, but I need an explanation.

Comment: I post the explanation. You can read the article for full understanding.